# Laravel 5.4 is not detecting submit button and MassAssignmentException _token error is given

Tags: php, laravel

View:

```
@extends('admin.layout.admin')
@section('content')
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Categories=></a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @if(!empty($categories))
        @forelse($categories as $category)
    <li>
        <a href="{{route('category.show',$category->id)}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
    </li>
        @empty
    <li>No Data</li>
        @endforelse
    @endif
    </ul>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-id">Add Category</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-id">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'category.store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Category</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('name','Name') }}
                        {{Form::text('name',null,array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="f btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="f data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $categories=Category::all();
        return view('admin.category.index',compact('categories'));
        }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Category::create($request->all());
        return back();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

"Submit" button is appearing in grey color instead of green as I'm using Php Storm. Any can help me what is problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you add

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

When you use a normal form not the collection HTML. In your model you have to pass the name of your input fileden

```
   // pass all the name in your form in your case just name
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

or you can use

```
protected $guarded // here you pass what is not going to add
```

Answer (score 2):

As to say about "MassAssignmentException", it means that you try to add new data, but haven't prepared the correct property $fillable

```
protected $fillable = ['name', ....];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

Also you could use $guared property, just to protect you data.

```
protected $guarded = ['price'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add csrf token field to your form to prevent token mismatch exception :

use this helper in your form :

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Also your submit button's class is `btn-primary` and this is not green!